# Utility for converting printouts to a large font

Tags: browser, printing, accessibility

My grandmother would like to be able to print articles from the web in large type, so that any visually impaired people she distributes the printouts to will have a better chance at reading them. She uses IE7 on Windows XP.

Sure, she could copy the text of the article to a document, set the font size as high as she likes, and print the document, but I'm hoping to find a tool that allows for a more streamlined process.

IE7's Page Setup allows you to select a font size, but it only allows up to 14-point. My grandmother would like to be able to do larger type.

What I'm looking for is basically a printing equivalent of a [Readability](http://lab.arc90.com/experiments/readability/) bookmark. Readability itself doesn't seem to do this. No matter what size text Readability displays on the screen, it always prints out with the same font size.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a "Granny" and I print pages quite often, several every day, and most from IE8.  Using "PrintWhatYouLike" was so confusing, sorry, but I found that if you right-click the page and select Print Preview, there is a box at the top that says "Shrink to fit."  Click that box and you'll see that you have the option to adjust the view on the page up to whatever percentage you want.  This enlarges the text, but also may be too much to fit on the page, so you may have to adjust margins of the pages, or select text to print and make sure it fits.

Comment: Thanks, "Granny"! That's even simpler than I'd expected to be able to find.

Answer (score 1):

Some browsers allow you change the scale of the page before printing.  For example, [Opera](http://www.opera.com)'s `Print Options` allow you to change the `Zoom` value from `100%` to something else.  You could set this to `150%` to make prints automatically zoom the pages by 150% when printing.

Also, Opera supports the Zoom function when viewing websites, you can even change the default zoom from 100% to something like 150% or 200%.  That will automatically scale up websites to larger fonts while maintaining the site's layout.

Comment: I'd rather not make her get used to a whole new browser.

Comment: While that may be true, it is a viable solution to your issue.  Which would be worse?  A new browser or unreadable web pages?  I'm just suggesting that you at least test to see if it is a valid solution.

Comment: Doesn't zoom in any browser just scale the site? Ie it will be much too wide to print... just changing the font size but not the layoyt seems like what's needed... it's a really weird decision to limit the font size at print-out to 14 in IE, awe-inspiringly stupid whoever came up with that validation ^^

Comment: That's likely, yes.  Opera has a Fit To Page option as well which tries to reflow a document to fit within the page.  Other browsers may support it, I just have the most experience with Opera.

Answer (score 1):

You could display the font of the web pages to be bigger, then print from there. Go to:

`View -> Text Size -> Largest`

Makes the page and printouts noticeably larger.

Answer (score 0):

I just found [PrintWhatYouLike.com](http://www.printwhatyoulike.com/), which provides a handy tool for this purpose. For some reason, the tool seems to have no effect on the text of an NYTimes story, although I can adjust the text size on other websites.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox allows you to set the font size higher than IE7. Just get her to download it, set up the font size for her under options, and not only have you solved the problem, your grandmother is now using a safer browser. Plus, the Firefox interface is much easier to use and customize. If your grandmother doesn't want to switch browsers, just use PrintWhatYouLike.com. Maybe IE8 has larger fonts, and she could probably upgrade to that if she likes IE7, the change is not that big. Or yet another option is go to Internet Options > General > Fonts and select a larger font while at the same time making the text size the largest.